# Can music be reduced to "gibberish"?

Tags: meaning, formality

I'm writing a formal essay, and I'm wondering about the usage of the word "gibberish."

According to Google, the definition of "gibberish" is `unintelligible or meaningless speech or writing; nonsense.`

I'm planning on saying "When played by the band, the song was reduced to gibberish."

Here, "gibberish" is neither speech nor writing, it's sound - music to be precise.

Is this still an appropriate use of "gibberish?"

Comment: You could use it that way metaphorically, but a better word might be *cacophony*.

Comment: Can dissonance fit the context here? It's synonymous with cacophony, but the main definition given by Google being, "lack of harmony among musical notes.", Since the example is music related.

Comment: @VanpramP Yeah, but it doesn't have the same strong effect. When something is dissonant is just sounds bad, and things can also be on-purposely dissonant, whereas this song was musically destroyed (reduced to gibberish).

Answer (score 1):

There are [two theories](http://gibfilm.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/did-gibberish-originally-describe.html) of the origin of the word 'gibberish' but they both say that  it refers to unintelligible speech with the '-ish' ending referring to language as in English, Danish, Spanish etc. That is the etymological theories conceive of 'gibberish' as being a language which "Isn't English, isn't Spanish, isn't Danish, it's gibberish.

Given this etymology I would say that that music can't be 'gibberish' as even music which is played properly isn't, strictly, a language. However lyrics certainly can be gibberish, particularly when someone with no understanding of a language tries to sing a song in that language. This can also apply to seriously drunk people at karaoke nights!